# How to rotate through entries in Database after a predetermined time

Tags: android, database, timer, countdowntimer

What I'm trying to achieve:

I'd like to pull data from a database and display it for a certain period of time, after that time expires it then pulls another entry from the Database. This would continue for a period of an hour.
To make it more complicated within the Database is the time value that the entry should be displayed for and I would also like this displayed as a countdown timer when the entry is displayed. The time value is different depending on the entry of the database.

Where I'm stuck:
I've created and loaded the database and can pull and display data from the database. The part where I am stuck is how do I add the timer function, ie displaying the entry for a certain period of time and then rolling it on to the next one. 
I also havent found a way to take the time value from the database and input it into a countdown timer.

Any pointers at where to start would be much appreciated!

Thanks

PS I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Sure .. you can use below function from Oracle which will enable you to wait for the desired time.
dbms_lock.sleep( Number_of_seconds );

U can fetch the value of waiting time from DB and then convert it into seconds and pass on that value to the above function.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the response ihm017. I should have said I've only just started programming so unfortunately the above doesnt mean much to me. How do I use dbms_lock.sleep in android studio. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Hello, sorry i didn't notice you are using Android Studio. In tht case you can use SLEEP function in the JAVA.